# if a tag contains image javascript

Tags: hyperlink, contains, skip

How to check if a tag contains image tag using javascript. I have to go through all the links on the site and Then add something to the text. I can do a loop to go over all the links on the page But I have to skip all the links (a tag) Contain a link with a img tag.

good for me

```
<a href='#'>abc</a>
```

not good for me

```
<a href='#'><img src='abc.com'></a>
```

Comment: using jQuery you could do something like $("a").children("img").length to get a count of how many img tags exist within the link tag.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery it could be:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('img').length === 0) {
        $(this).text('New text');
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xv4G3/)